# Methods to add top space to elements in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace, margin

I am wondering if there is a preferred method to add top-space to shift things down in BS.

My 2 thoughts were using something similar to this

http://pdenya.com/2013/08/08/vertical-space-in-bootstrap/

or creating blank space holders `<div>`.

I need to be be able to remove the top space as it collapses down to mobile size so I can probably just put a `hidden-xs`

Are there other methods that are better than these two? I think the space holder method is probably least preferred

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to add `margin-top` and if you don't need the margin on mobile just use a media query with the grid size that you require.

```
.margin-desktop {
   margin-top: 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {

  .margin-desktop{
     margin-top: 0px;
  }

}
```